# Android Push Notifications not appearing when app is fully closed (using node-gcm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the [node-gcm](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm) module to send Push Notifications to my Cordova app.
The server reports that it has successfully delivered the message to my device.

The notifications **appear on the device if the app is running in the background, but do not come up if the app is not running at all**.

From [my reading](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) I believe I need to set `priority: 'high'` to fix this, however from my tests this does not work.  Either I am setting that incorrectly, or there is something else I need to do.

Here is my send code:

```
var msgJson = {
                priority: 'high',
                contentAvailable: true,
                "data": {
                    title: title,
                    body: message_text,
                    icon: 'ic_launcher',
                    sound: true,
                    extra_data
                }
};


var message = new gcm.Message( msgJson );

console.log(message);

sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: push_tokens }, function (err, response) {

    if(err) {
        console.error('Error sending Google Cloud Message notification:', err, response);
    } else {
        console.log('Android notification successful send to', push_tokens, response);
    }

});
```

Why are my notifications not coming up on the device when the app is fully closed?

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24340912/5832311) that force stopping an application by the user puts the application in a stopped state and none of its code is run, including any broadcast receivers declared in manifest. Only when the user explicitly launches the app it is put in a state where the receivers get fired.

You can also read in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) that the value of `delay_while_idle` must be set to `true`. If the device is connected but idle, the message will still be delivered right away unless the `delay_while_idle` flag is set to true.

Here's a related thread which might help:

- [Push not received when app is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603935/push-not-received-when-app-is-killed)

Comment: I did do a fair bit of research myself before posting an answer and I had come across that same information that broadcasts don't arrive if the app is fully closed - but I just can't believe it, some apps (like gmail) do manage it.  I also tried the delay_while_idle flag, but I believe that is for a network connectivity thing and so I left it out of my answer that I had tried that.  I appreciate your research and your leaving an answer -- I'm really hoping to get an answer from someone who has actually faced and solved the same problem.

Comment: I have come across something that I think is likely the way to go, and I will try it next, but it requires modifying my client code so I'd put it off until last : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24314088/1290746   (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313539/push-notifications-when-app-is-closed)  Again - thank you for your answer and I hope my reply didn't sound ungrateful - I've spent a long time on this with little luck and no success and I am feeling very tired and sad.